# Image classification using cnn

Tags: python, neural-network, image-classification, convolution, image-recognition

I did image classification using CNN and it successfully classified the images  but How to save predicted images to separate folder for example i have two classes cat and dog after prediction how to save predicted cats images to cat folder and dog images to dogs folder

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a library or module that will do this for you, but it should be simple enough to handle. If you saved the image names in your original dataset while loading, you can add the predictions to that same dataset and then loop through row by row, renaming the image based on the classification category.

Comment: Thank you i will try